# Assign array value to local variable

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, for-loop

I am fetching some records and they contains an array that contains two further fields. For example, fetched data is like this:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Govind", "Array": [{"subject": "maths", "score": 70}, {"subject": "maths", "score": 80}, {"subject": "english", "score": 90}]}
```

I want to assign value of `"score"` to a local variable where `"subject"` is `"maths"`, so that I can have something like this:

```
var1 = 70 and var2 = 80
```

code snap:

```
try :
cursor = db.students.find().sort('_id',pymongo.ASCENDING)

for loop in cursor:
    for item in loop:
        if loop[item] is "type":
           #here i need to check value of array elements and then remove them from array.  
           print key #loop[item]
```

first for loop gives me record.
second for loop loops over the item of which one is array
I further need to access array elements and do comparison for lower value.

The output i get is like this

```
**193
govind
[{u'score': 47 , u'type': u'exam'}, {u'score': 41 ,
u'type': u'quiz'}, {u'score': 70 , u'type': u'homework'}, {u'score'
: 48 , u'type': u'homework'}]**
```

Comment: i want to compare the scores of "maths" and then remove the array element with low score.

Comment: this example is representing a scenario, not actual the actual data. my purpose it to remove record from an array with lower score.

Comment: My final output record will be:{"id": 1, "name": "Govind", "Array": [ {"subject": "maths", "score": 80}, {"subject": "english", "score": 90}]

Comment: as you can see the array in output will not be having {Maths : 70 } value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80456/discussion-between-govind-chouhan-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

loop on the array and the access the elements using

```
loopindex[key]
```